# How to assign static ip to devices connecting over wifi using Network Manager?

Tags: wifi, ip, networkmanager, mac-address

I have several devices connected to my wifi, and I need to assign them a static ip address, but NetworkManager gives them sometimes different ip addresses. I tried adding a file in /etc/network/if-up.d/ with the command

arp -i wlp6s0 -s 10.42.0.2 e8:b4:c8:2a:5c:45

but didn't work, then I tried disabling NetworkManager dnsmasq with no results. The device still has the ip 10.42.0.37. Any thoughts?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Is your laptop acting as wifi? If yes, then NetworkManager doesn't assign ipaddress. Dnsmasq does that.

Comment: Yes, my laptop is acting as a wifi router. Am sharing internet from the ethernet adapter through wifi. Ok, at this point the question is how can I configure dnsmasq to assign static ip addresses by mac address? if this can be done of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with Network Manager is that it calls dnsmasq for configuring dns and dhcp when the wifi acts as an Access Point. You can overwrite that configuration by adding files with the .conf extension into the directory

**/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d/**

And thats all.

In my case I added a few lines configuring dhcp to asssign static ip by mac address, this is the content of the file:

---

**static-ips.conf**

> dhcp-host=e8:b4:c8:2a:5a:48,10.42.0.25
>   
> (....)

Comment: This worked amazingly well in 20.04.1 I just had to turn off the connection and turn it back on. After 20 seconds the clients got the message. Note, if NM fails to turn it back on, `killall dnsmasq`

I'm happy to have such a powerful zero latency setup

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have access to these devices or know what operating systems they're using or what kind of devices they may be, there really isn't a way to do this from your Ubuntu device. Most likely, you'll need third-party software that can assign IP addresses via MAC addresses.

Comment: The static ip addresses are for the devices connected to my interface, not the interface itself, and I want to assign those ips by mac.

Comment: I know. I'm suggesting that you edit the /etc/network/interface and /etc/resolv.conf files on the devices themselves. It's more tedious but it gets the job done.

Comment: That's OK, but I don't have access to the devices, and they have different operating systems, they could be even mobile phones.

Comment: I understand. I'll update my answer.